# regex in location block of nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, rate-limiting, nginx-config

I want to enable rate limiting on my nginx for various accounts like 5010 and 5011.

When I uncomment the commented line for only account 5010, it works perfectly fine.

I tried the following code block but it's not working.

```
   location ^~ /google/(5010|5011)/photos {
   #location ^~ /google/5010/photos {
        #apply rate limiting
        limit_req zone=sone burst=1 nodelay;
        limit_req_status 429;
        limit_conn_status 429;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `~*` instead of `^~`:

```
location ~* /google/(5010|5011)/photos
```

Fron the [docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location):

> A location can either be defined by a prefix string, or by a regular expression. Regular expressions are specified with the preceding “~*” modifier (for case-insensitive matching), or the “~” modifier (for case-sensitive matching).

for `^~`

> if the longest matching prefix location has the “^~” modifier then regular expressions are not checked.